# How to position div inside middle of navbar?

Tags: html, css

The end goal for this will be to have "CodePlayer" on the far left, the .toggles ul ("HTML/CSS/JS/Result") lined up in the very middle, and the "run" button that says on the far right.

My instructor always has us using float: left and float: right to align items inside the div, and from all that I've learned on here, that's a horrible way to do things. So, I'm trying to go rogue and start using display: inline-block, but I can't figure out how to get "html/css/js/result" lined up in the middle of the page.

How do I get each respective div to be on the left, in the middle, and on the right?

http://jsfiddle.net/m2c4j3bu/

CSS:

```
    body {
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
        font-weight: 300;
    }


    #menuBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2.5em;
        background-color: #E6E6E6; 

    }


    #logo {
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 1em; 
        font-family: helvetica; 
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px; 
        vertical-align: top; 

    }

    #buttonDiv {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #togglesDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .toggles li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 5px; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menuBar">

        <div id="logo">CodePlayer</div>

        <ul class="toggles">
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JS</li>
            <li>Result</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="buttonDiv">

            <button id="runButton">Run</button>

        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display: table`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
            font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
            font-weight: 300;
        }


        #menuBar {
            width: 100%;
            height: 2.5em;
            background-color: #E6E6E6; 
            display: table;     
        }

#logo,
#buttonDiv,
.toggles{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
     width: 25%;
}
        #logo {
            font-weight: bold; 
            font-size: 1em; 
            font-family: helvetica;              
        }

        #buttonDiv {
            text-align: right;
        }
       
.toggles{
    text-align: center;   
   width: 50%;
    background: #ddd;
}
        .toggles li {
         list-style: none;
          display: inline-block;      
           vertical-align: middle;
           padding: 0 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="menuBar">

            <div id="logo">CodePlayer</div>
            
            <ul class="toggles">
                <li>HTML
                <li>CSS
                <li>JS
                <li>Result
            </ul>
            
            <div id="buttonDiv">
            
                <button id="runButton">Run</button>
            
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! You were the only one who got this exactly the way I was wanting it to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `inline-block` styling, style the `div` elements within the `#menuBar` id as `table-cells` and they'll position evenly across the width.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2c4j3bu/2/)**

Here's the major update:

```
#menuBar {
   display:table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 2.5em;
   background-color: #E6E6E6; 
}
#menuBar div {
   display:table-cell; /* Maintains the spacing across the width */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've changed a bit of your HTML structure (just added a wrapper `div` `#nav` to wrap your toggles)

I've made following changes (commented) in CSS

```
#logo {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left; /* Added */
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px; /* Replaced your margin with padding */
    width: 33.33333333%; /* Added */
}
/* Wrapper for your toggles */
#nav {
    float: left;
    width:33.33333333%;
    text-align: center;
}

#buttonDiv {
    float: left; /* Added */
    width:33.33333333%; /* Added */
    text-align: right; /* Added */
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0px; /* Added */
}
```

And I've also edited some CSS for your toggles `<li>` elements

```
.toggles li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block; /* Added */
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg3d4fgd/)